# 2 tasks on single button click in ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to perform two tasks on click on a single link. For example, clicking on an coupon link should take the user to the merchant's website on a new page and the page where the link was clicked should display the coupon code. This is similar to what happens in Coupondunia etc...

Right now I have a single link, if I click it, it opens a new page, but does not perform the second action that I mentioned earlier, could you please provide me any insights?

I am using ASP.net MVC

```
 <a href="www.xyz.com">TestLink</a>
```

Comment: How about passing a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in that href, that tells the new page what coupon code to display?

Comment: Yes, that will open the merchant's website on the new page, but on the same page I want a dialog which should display the coupon code.

Comment: Do you have control over the merchant's website, or is it a third-party site?

Comment: It is a third party site, but the url which I will hit will be a custom url configured for my website.

Comment: Then I think you need to ask the merchant site (assuming they'll help...) how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript for this. With straight HTML clicking a link will only perform one action: issuing a GET request to the specified URL. To pop your dialog, you need only add an event handler to the link's `click` event that will show that dialog. Something along the lines of:

```
$('#MyLink').on('click', function () {
    // show dialog
});
```

The default action, requesting the URL, will happen regardless, unless you stop it with either `evt.preventDefault()` or by returning `false`. As a result, you don't need to add anything special in that regard.

However, bear in mind, that unless the link has a `target` attribute, it will load in the same browser tab/window, meaning that by the time your dialog displays, the entire page view would have changed to the new URL. As a result, you should ensure that the link opens in a new tab/window, by adding `target="_blank"` (or a more specific target) to your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

@alok...hey brother...are u asking for something like this ...that i mentioned below...let me know...if it is what you are asking for or not...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DemoButton</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id ="Demo_Btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="test1(), test2()"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test1() {
//define your test1 here...
 }

   function test2() {
   //define your test2 here...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like the code you posted should work, yes I am asking for something like that, I will try to implement it and mark it as an answer if it works. Thanks for giving your time brother.